# Blackberry Build Error

Tags: blackberry

I am getting the following error when building the app using Blackberry JDE editor:

> Building HelloWorld
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In
>   Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.1.0\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=HelloWorld
>   HelloWorld.rapc
>   warnkey=0x52424200;0x52525400;0x5242534b;0x42424944;0x52435200;0x4e464352;0x52455345
>   import="....\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE
>   7.1.0\lib\net_rim_api.jar" C:\Projects\BeginningBlackBerryDevelopment\com\beginningblackberry\helloworld\HelloWorldApp.java
>
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory
>   "C:\Projects\BeginningBlackBerryDevelopment"): CreateProcess error=2,
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Error while building
>   project

Comment: I think you need to edit/update Environment variable `PATH`, check this answer, Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14919285/431639.

Answer (score 1):

I would try **reinstalling** your JDE.  Something looks like it got messed up during installation.

I am able to install and run JDE 7.1 on a Windows 7 machine (64-bit, with the install directory set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\`), using the `BlackBerry_JDE_7.1.0.exe` file on blackberry.com published 7/12/2012.

If reinstalling doesn't work, then the next time you install, try to pick a new directory to install in.  Instead of

```
c:\program files (x86)\research in motion\
```

as the root folder, make a new folder yourself:

```
c:\RIM\
```

and install there.  It looks like somehow your command line is having trouble with file paths that include spaces.

Also, the JDE is now quite old.  I would generally recommend trying to use the Eclipse Plugin, although from your other question, it looks like you're having trouble with that, too :(

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the JDE to c:/rim worked for me.